# Creating Blog in the Brooklyn theme for Shopify

Tags: themes, shopify, blogs, liquid

SO I have been struggling with incorporating a blog into the Brooklyn theme on Shopify. I know there has to be a way to connect a blog to this theme, but I have had no luck with finding good documentation on how to do this. Any suggestions or tips would be absolutely awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It comes built in :)

Check out the documentation here: https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/online-store/blogs

Comment: It does come built in, but not all the themes utilize the blog. I need to be able to add a blog section to the theme editor, so it will show the two latest blog posts on my store front.

Comment: Here is the default Brooklyn theme blog page. 
https://brooklyn-theme.myshopify.com/blogs/news

If you'd like to expose the blog posts on the homepage that's a theme customization that any shopify developer can likely help you out with. 
See https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/help-how-to-add-blog-posts-to-homepage-360787 for reference.

Comment: Thanks man, I guess I just need to figure out how to add it to the sections correctly.